# Finding SVD efficiently for $AB^T$

Tags: ds.algorithms, linear-algebra, matrices

I have a low rank matrix given as $AB^T$ where $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ and $p \ll n$. (I know $A$ and $B$ separately)

**EDIT:** (I have added the second question here since it was [closed as a duplicate](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5871/svd-of-product-of-two-matrices) of this question. Note that  the optimal algorithm for the low rank version $p \ll n$ will not work for this.)

In general, if we have two full rank square matrices, what is the most efficient way to find SVD of a product of two matrices say A×B ? (Is it possible to find the SVD without explicitly multiplying them out?).

Is there a relation between the SVD of the product A×B and the SVD of the individual matrices (A and B) ?

**Back to the first question:**

One efficient way to get the Singular Value Decomposition when $p \ll n$ is to do a reduced QR on $A$ and $B$ i.e.

$A = Q_A R_A$ and $B = Q_B R_B$.

The above can be done in $\mathcal{O}(p^2n)$ cost.

I could then compute the svd of $R_A R_B^T = U_1 \Sigma V_1^T$ which is $\mathcal{O}(p^3)$.

Hence this will give me $$AB^T = (Q_A U_1) \Sigma (Q_B V_1)^T$$

The total cost is $\mathcal{O}(np^2)$.

However, I am wondering if there are other efficient ways to go about doing this to reduce the coefficient infront of $p^2n$. If I am right, the coefficient infront of $np^2$ is $3$ if we go about doing QR. The reason why I am interested in minimizing the coefficient is that my $n$ is really ginormous. So if I were to implement it, a cost cutting on the coefficient of the $\mathcal{O}(n)$ could be significant.

I am wondering if we could exploit the fact that the left singular vectors must span $A$ and the right singular vectors span $B$

i.e. we know that if $AB^T = U \Sigma V^T$, then

$$A = U \alpha \text{ and } B = V \beta$$

and we want $\alpha \beta^T$ to be diagonal and $U$,$V$ needs to be unitary.

**EDIT** What I essentially want is an exact rank $r<p$ approximation to the product $AB^T$ in the form $U_r V_r^T$. I am not looking for approximate or probabilistic algorithms.

Comment: [Crosspost on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/27730/2767).

Comment: I posted it on math.SE today hoping I could get an answer.

Comment: @Sivaram Ambikasaran, it is common to at least wait a few days before cross-posting on other sites. (You should also link to the cross-posted versions in the question.)

Comment: Wikipedia claims that Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization has a constant of 2 (instead of 3 for Householder), but I did not check the claim. It might be worth trying. However, in the end you have to *somehow* orthogonalize the columns of $A$. If you can do that substantially better than QR, then your technique could be used to beat QR in general (which is unlikely).

Comment: @Milos: Thanks. But GS is unstable. Instead of doing QR twice once on A and once on B, can we get around it say by doing QR once just on A or B and then manipulate? or as I have mentioned in the post, is there a way to simplify the entire thing since we know that the left singular vectors span A and the right singular vectors span B?

Comment: Sivaram, I think the fact that the left singular vectors span A is precisely the problem. That's because QR can be seen as an algorithm that orthogonalizes the columns of an arbitrary A. If you come up with a fundamentally faster way to solve the problem "give me an orthogonal set of vectors that spans the same space as columns of A", you could probably you use it to speed up QR.

Comment: This is not my area of expertise but I really don't think anyone would compute the product $AB$ to get its SVD. The typical numerical method is the Golub-Kahan bidiagonalization process, which only requires matrix-vector products with $AB$ and its transpose. It doesn't require the matrix itself. From this it generates an upper (or lower) bidiagonal matrix that has the same singular values as $AB$. I believe what happens next is a QR factorization. See http://goo.gl/YS7Q6 for all details.